# Develop with Parity?

Tags: contract-deployment, parity, parity-wallet

I've seen a few tutorials that explain how to write contract code right inside the Parity's web interface. However, web interface says it's deprecated, and when I open the desktop UI, it doesn't have any option to open an editor.

Is it possible to write/test/deploy a contract using the Parity UI program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can develop and deploy contracts in Parity UI using the **Develop contracts** dapp. This dapp is bundled (installed by default) with Parity UI and should show up in the dapps list when opening Parity UI.

Comment: My problem was that I user the light mode, and the UI didn't show anything